# SQL NOT IN (Do not know anyone who smokes)

Tags: sql

So I have these three tables:

```
Persons {id, name}
Knows {A_id, B_id}  - (Person A knows Person B)
Smoking {id} - (id -> Persons{id})

Persons:
{1, "Tim"}
{2, "Kim"}
{3, "Jim"}
{4, "Rim"}

Knows:
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
{3, 2}
{3, 4}

Smoking:
{3}
```

And I need {3, "Jim"} to be returned since he doesn't know anyone who smokes ({1, "Tim"} knows Jim who smokes so he's out)

I tried this query:

```
SELECT P.name 
FROM Persons P, Knows K
WHERE K.A_id = P.id AND K.B_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Smokes)
```

but it still return "Tim" even he knows 2 people and only 1 of them is smoking. And I need only the persons who's EVERY 'friend' doesn't smoke.. Help!

Comment: doesn't really answer your question, but it makes a lot more sense to have the `Smokes` column in your `Persons` table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM Persons p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                -- there does not exist
   SELECT * FROM Knows k          -- a person I know
   JOIN smokes s ON s.id = k.b_id -- who smokes
   WHERE k.A_id = p.id
   );
```

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to explain how to think about your problem in set theory / SQL terms:

1. You need an aggregated sum  of the total number of people that any given person knows who smokes.
2. Then filter for people where that aggregated value is zero.

That leads to:

```
select P.Name
  from Persons P inner join Knows K on K.A_Id = P.ID
  left join Smoking on Smoking.ID = P.B_Id
 group by person
having sum(smoking.ID) = 0
```

Comment: Sorry, yes it should be Smoking.ID, and COUNT() or SUM() will suffice.

Comment: Presumably "Knows" is reflexive so Persons could join to either column in it...  At the moment for example Kim and Rim will never be returned as people because they won't match `K.A_Id = P.ID`...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find all the people who don't know a smoker, I think it would be easier to find all the people who do know a smoker and then invert the result

```
select * 
from        persons P 
LEFT JOIN   smoking s 
            INNER JOIN  knows k
                    on  k.B_id = s.id       
            on k.A_id = P.id 
where       s.id is null
```

The inner join between Knows and Smoker will be run to find all people who know a smoker. The where clause will then filter all the people out who know a smoker.